# Referencing \mathcal Variables Orally

Tags: notation

It is common in machine learning papers to see notation such as

$$X \in \mathcal{X}$$

where both variables are "X" but one is in calligraphy (`\mathcal` in typesetting).  When reading a document using such notation, the difference between variables is obvious, but orally "X in X" may be confusing to some listeners.

Is there a standard (or even common) parlance/notation used to refer to calligraphic letters orally?

Comment: I heard that someone is saying ‘curl X’, but I am not sure if it is for the frak font or the other one.

Comment: I have most often heard "script X." Strictly speaking, if one were to be faithful to Latex's nomenclature it should be "calligraphic X" for `\mathcal{X}` $\mathcal{X}$, and "script X" for `\mathscr{X}` $\mathscr{X}$ but I don't know if people make this distinction in real life.

Comment: @J1U I would think that "curl $X$" could be dangerous, as the curl of a vector field is a thing.  Are you sure that they weren't saying "cal $X$"?

Comment: @XanderHenderson I am still not sure, but maybe it was ‘curly X’, not ‘curl X’.